# Reading Empty CSV Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a process to read csv files and do some processing in pyspark. At times I might get a zero byte empty file. In such cases when I use the below code

```
df = spark.read.csv('/path/empty.txt', header = False)
```

It is failing with error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o139.csv.
>   : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty collection

Since its empty file I tried to read as a json it worked fine

```
df = spark.read.json('/path/empty.txt')
```

When I add header to the empt `csv` manually to the code reads fine.

```
df = spark.read.csv('/path/empty.txt', header = True)
```

In few places I read to use databricks csv but 
I don't have the data bricks csv package options to use as those jars are not available in my environment.

Comment: What exactly is your *question*?